# ESC/POS printer Java

Tags: java, c, printing

I have a DateCS MP55 cashregister. I want to develop a code in Java for it to print. The documentation is very poor and i could use some help.I've read somewhere that i need to send a command to it's port, but i don't know what command and also the way i am sending it, just how to get the port it uses.  What i found so far :

```
1.1. PrnOpen Opens the serial port and performs initalization of the printer 
Syntax int __stdcall PrnOpen(int port, int speed, bool hardware); 
Parameters port com port number speed com port speed hardware if true, turns on RTS/CTS handshaking, false goes back to XON/OFF 
Return value ERR_OK - printer is ready ERR_TIMEOUT - communication error
```

So this look like its C code. I've created a sample code for test but C doesn't have bool type ... :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void helloFromC(){
    printf("Hello from C!");
}
int __stdcall PrnOpen(int port, int speed, bool hardware);

int main(){
 helloFromC();
 return 0;
}
```

So without `int __stdcall PrnOpen(int port, int speed, bool hardware);` i am able to run the code in Java.
Also, the way i am calling this C code in Java :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String filename = "D:\\eclipse\\workspace\\Testing\\TestFile.exe";
            Runtime rTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = rTime.exec(filename);
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how i am creating a communication with ports :

```
import java.util.*;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;

/** List all the ports available on the local machine. **/
public class ListPorts
{
public static void main (String args[])
{

Enumeration port_list = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
System.out.println("START");
while (port_list.hasMoreElements())
{   
    CommPortIdentifier port_id = (CommPortIdentifier)port_list.nextElement();
    if (port_id.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
        System.out.println("Serial port: "+ port_id.getName());
    else if (port_id.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL)
    {
        System.out.println("Parallel port: "+ port_id.getName());
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Other port: "+ port_id.getName());

}
System.out.println("END");
} // main
} // class PortList
```

Comment: "C doesn't have bool type" is wrong! It is standard since C99. What was the question?

Comment: What i have to do to make the cashregister print ?